# Session under class

Tags: php

Hello i just stuck in syntax, can anyone help me with next code?

```
class User {    
  protected $userID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user_id']);
  protected $useremail = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9@_.-]#i', '', $_SESSION['user']);
  protected $userPassword = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user_password']);

  public function CheckUserLogin(){     
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
      header("location: login.php");
      exit();    
    }

    //Try to find user from session data in database
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$this->userID' AND email = '$this->useremail' AND password = '$this->userPassword' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $userMatch = mysql_numrows($res);
    if ($userMatch == 0) {
      header("location: login.php");
      exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\social\libs\user.php on line 6

i cant do protected $userPassword = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user_password']); i don't now why

Answer (score 4):

First of all, note that when declaring a property, you cannot assign it a value that's not know at compile-time -- which means you cannot call a function to initialize a property.

This code :

```
protected $userID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user_id']);
```

Is not valid.

As a reference, you can read the [**Properties**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) page of the manual (quoting the relevant sentence) :

> They are defined by using one of the keywords `public`, `protected`,
>   or `private`, followed by a normal variable declaration. 
> This
>   declaration may include an initialization, but **this initialization
>   must be a constant value** -- that is, it must be able to be evaluated
>   at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order
>   to be evaluated.

You should first declare the property ; and, later *(in the [constructor](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) of your class, for instance)*, initialize it :

```
class User {

    protected $userID;

    public function __construc() {
        $this->userID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user_id']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short: You can only assign constant expressions to properties within the class declaration (within the class body, but outside a method). Everything else (variables, function calls, ...) are restricted to code blocks (main, functions and methods).

However, your code in the way you show it is very magic, what you should avoid in any case. Use the constructor instead

```
class User {    
  protected $userID;
  protected $useremail;
  protected $userPassword;

  public function __construct ($userId, $user, $password) {
    $this->userID = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $userId);
    $this->useremail = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9@_.-]#i', '', $user);
    $this->userPassword = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i', '', $password);
  }

  // ..
}
```